# XAMPP phpmyadmin is blank when tried to accessed

Tags: php, xampp

In XAMPP, MySQL and Apache starts successfully and xampp's dashboard is accessible. But when I try to access `phpmyadmin` it displays nothing i.e, it displays a blank window displaying nothing.

[image]

I've tried different versions for xampp and even tried reinstalling and changing ports.

I work on WINDOWS 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: You'll most likely need to edit your php.ini and change display_errors = Off to display_errors = On. Then you'll be able to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Go to php.ini file, find `open_basedir`, then comment it by introducing ';'(semi-colon) as depicted below

```
;open_basedir = "C:\xampp\htdocs"
```